# Pod install -> error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: firebase, react-native, cocoapods

Estoy intentando crear una aplicación básica con react-native que use firebase usando los pasos definidos en https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/basic-kit, pero en el tercer paso, cuando ejecuto el comando "pod install" dentro de la carpeta IOS obtengo el siguiente error:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for arm-apple-darwin-gcc...  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
checking whether the C compiler works... no
/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
/bin/bash: line 24: xcrun: command not found
/home/mistermboy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
Try `/home/mistermboy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da/missing --help' for more information
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
configure: error: in `/home/mistermboy/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/glog/2263bd123499e5b93b5efe24871be317-1f3da':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Release: 18.04
- Codename:    bionic
- x86_64
- NPM Version: 6.13.4
- Node Version: v12.14.1
- Pod Version: 1.8.4

Comment: Uno de los requisitos del paso 3 es que tengas Xcode. Deberías intentar en una Mac o en una Máquina virtual con Mac OSX.

Comment: Entonces no hay manera de utilizar firebase para ios en react-native sin disponer de un Mac?

Comment: Me temo que no. Cualquier desarrollo para iOS necesita su OSX nativo. Intenta descargar una máquina virtual que ya vienen preinstaladas OSX Capitan.

Comment: Microsoft tiene un servicio gratis para compilar los aplicaciones react-native. Se llama [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms) y viene con [react-native-code-push](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) que es una herramienta muy cómoda para react-native